# SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal (gdrive)

Tags: python, syntax-error, decimal, literals, drive

```
user_interactions_df = pd.read_csv(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WgjXneyZHGQrxrh1maRyPdbXE3J9wp--)
                                                                                  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYlcQ.png)

Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

I just want to run my code!!
Firstt time on stack overflow:)
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `read_csv()` function takes a string argument containing the file path.

What you are trying to do will not work, as `pd.read_csv()` can not request the file from a web address. Download the .csv file and pass the file path to the function as an argument.

Check out the pandas `read_csv()` documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html